# How to complete instalation ant then restart windows?

Tags: visual-c++, inno-setup

I try to rework existing inno setup script and include some dependencies to it. But at the middle of installation VC++ redistributable always restart the windows not from installing wizard window. And this restart totally has broken all installation progress. I have this script.

```
[Files]
    Source: "E:\engine\repos\AACPsychologue_all\aacpsychologue\Installers\Launcher\AAC Psychologue.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
    Source: "E:\engine\repos\AACPsychologue_all\aacpsychologue\Installers\Launcher\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
    Source: "E:\engine\repos\AACPsychologue_all\aacpsychologue\Installers\Resources\dxwebsetup.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; AfterInstall: DirecXinstaller; Flags: ignoreversion deleteafterinstall
    Source: "E:\engine\repos\AACPsychologue_all\aacpsychologue\Installers\Resources\Windows6.1-KB2670838-x64.msu"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: 64bit deleteafterinstall
    Source: "E:\engine\repos\AACPsychologue_all\aacpsychologue\Installers\Resources\Windows6.1-KB2670838-x86.msu"; DestDir: "{app}"; AfterInstall: Win7Update; Flags: 32bit deleteafterinstall
    Source: "E:\engine\repos\AACPsychologue_all\aacpsychologue\Installers\Resources\Windows6.1-KB2670838-x86.msu"; DestDir: "{app}"; AfterInstall: Win7Update; Flags: 32bit deleteafterinstall
    Source: "E:\engine\repos\AACPsychologue_all\aacpsychologue\Installers\Resources\vc_redist.x86.exe"; DestDir: "{app}";AfterInstall: vcInstaller; Flags: 32bit deleteafterinstall
    Source: "E:\engine\repos\AACPsychologue_all\aacpsychologue\Installers\Resources\vc_redist.x64.exe"; DestDir: "{app}";AfterInstall: vcInstaller; Flags: 64bit deleteafterinstall

    ; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

    [Icons]
    Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"      
    Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}";

    [Code]

    procedure DirecXinstaller;
    var
      ResultCode: Integer;
    begin
      if not Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\dxwebsetup.exe'), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL,
        ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
      then
        MsgBox('Other installer failed to run!' + #13#10 +
          SysErrorMessage(ResultCode), mbError, MB_OK);
    end;


    procedure Win7Update;
    var
      ResultCode: Integer;
    begin
      if IsWin64 then
      begin
        Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\Windows6.1-KB2670838-x64.msu'), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL,
        ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
      end
      else
      begin
        Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\Windows6.1-KB2670838-x86.msu'), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL,
        ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
      end;
    end;

    procedure vcInstaller;
    var
      ResultCode: Integer;
    begin
      if IsWin64 then
        begin
          Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\vc_redist.x64.exe'), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewNoWait, ResultCode)
        end
      else
        begin
          Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\vc_redist.x86.exe'), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewNoWait, ResultCode)
        end;
    end;


    [Run]
    Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Flags: postinstall skipifsilent waituntilterminated unchecked;
```

Have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`vc_redist.*.exe` have `/norestart` switch to prevent the restart.

You can then make Inno Setup restart the machine using [`AlwaysRestart` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_alwaysrestart).

---

Also, note that it is better to use `[Run]` section to execute the sub-installer. Additionally, it not a good practice to install temporary files to `{app}`. I also do not think that you want to use `ewNoWait`.

```
[Setup]
AlwaysRestart=yes

[Files]
Source: "...\vc_redist.x86.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: 32bit
Source: "...\vc_redist.x64.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: 64bit

[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\vc_redist.x86.exe"; Parameters: "/norestart"; Flags: 32bit
Filename: "{tmp}\vc_redist.x64.exe"; Parameters: "/norestart"; Flags: 64bit
```